# Creating a javascript object from a string for use with datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, datatables

This question is regarding the plugin found here: http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns

```
var hidecols = '{"sClass": "Hide", "aTargets": [0]},{"sClass": "asdf", "aTargets": [1]},{"sClass": "qwer", "aTargets": [2]}';

var hidecolsobj = eval('(' + hidecols + ')');


        var oTable = $('#MainContent_OverviewTable').dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "aoColumnDefs":
            [
                hidecolsobj, // <--------- *** HERE ***
            ],
            "sAjaxSource": "Services/Service.svc/GetDataTableOutputOverview",
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                var jsonAOData = JSON.stringify(aoData);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: true,
                    url: sSource,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: '{"Input":' + jsonAOData + '}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        fnCallback(msg);
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
                        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

So the code works fine with no errors but the class "qwer" is the only one that is being applied to my table. I tested this out and it only applies the class that appears last in my list of objects. I would like each of the columns to have the classes defined in the hidecols variable. How can I do that?

This is how it appears in the documentation from the Datatables website:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [ 
        { "sClass": "my_class", "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
    ]
} );
```

EDIT:

```
            "aoColumnDefs":
            [
                { "sClass": "Hide", "aTargets": [0] },
                { "sClass": "asdf", "aTargets": [1] }, 
                { "sClass": "qwer", "aTargets": [2] }
            ],
```

The above edit works properly but this isn't an option for me. I need to be able to build the string hidecols dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing DataTables a string for the aoColumnDefs parameter. Just remove the quote marks around the hidecols "string" to make it an array of objects. That will remove the need for the evil (eval).

```
var hidecols = [{"sClass": "Hide", "aTargets": [0]},{"sClass": "asdf", "aTargets": [1]},{"sClass": "qwer", "aTargets": [2]}];
```

Allan

Comment: Hmm.. I'd like to get rid of the eval, but can I build up hidecols programatically if its an object and not a string?

Comment: Yes indeed you can. Just something like `hidecols.push({"sClass": "NewClass", "aTargets": [2]});`. It's just manipulating an array.

Comment: oh -_- yeah. I knew that! I swear! :) Thanks a bunch, Allan!

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I figured out how to do it!

Instead of doing this:

```
        "aoColumnDefs":
        [
            hidecolsobj, // <--------- *** HERE ***
        ],
```

I should be doing this:

```
    var hidecols = '[{"sClass": "Hide", "aTargets": [0]},{"sClass": "asdf", "aTargets": [1]},{"sClass": "qwer", "aTargets": [2]}]';
var hidecolsobj = eval('(' + hidecols + ')');
            "aoColumnDefs": hidecolsobj, // <--------- *** HERE ***
```